# Building view from model directly In Codeigniter?

Tags: php

I have a header that contains a navigation menu for categories.

this menu is created by data from database, and I've created a model, and this is the function which returns the categories list in that model :

```
function categories_list()
  {
    $query=$this->db->get("produits_categories");
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
      $i = 0;
      foreach($query->result() as $rows)
      {
        $items[$i] = $rows->title;
        $i++;
      }
      return $items;
```

the problem is that I don't know how to use the controller to pass data to the header view, because the header view is called by other controllers.

for exemple I have the client controller which load the header view, the client view and the footer view, so if I need to pass data I have to call the categorie controller and pass data to the header view in every page that uses the header.

Isn't there any other method to pass data to view directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding part of your question, it is possible to pass data directly to a view as followed:

```
$data = 'Some Data You Create';
$this->load->view('view_in_question', $data);
```

This is standard syntax for passing data to a view which is usually easy to do in codeigniter. Here is the section of the user guide that covers this in more detail:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 2):

When the controller applies a view, it can [pass parameters](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) (see the section *Adding Dynamic Data to the View* about halfway down).  That is the proper approach to take at some level.

Philosophically, it could be that a menu is completely independent of the page being displayed.  In that case it might be acceptable for the view to retrieve its data rather than having the controller do it every time.

Comment: what I mean is that the menu of categories has always the same code and if I used passed data using a controller I have to call this controller every time I want to display the header, I want in the code of the header to retrieve data and display it with a foreach loop without calling a contoller

Comment: @AzerRtyu:  Your wording suggests that perhaps you don't understand the role of the controller.  A [controller](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) is activated by a page load and normally calls models and views.  It would be unusual–and highly questionable–for a view to call a controller.